# SVN Client Ignore Pattern for VB.NET Solutions

Tags: vb.net, svn, tortoisesvn

What is the best SVN Ignore Pattern should TortoiseSVN have for a VB.NET solution?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

this is what I use for C# w/resharper, should work just the same with vb.net:

```
build deploy */bin  */bin/* obj *.dll *.pdb *.user *.suo _ReSharper*  *.resharper* bin
```

Comment: If you're using hg (mercurial) then don't forget to add a "syntax: glob" on the top of all in the .hgignore file.

Answer (score 4):

I always add Thumbs.db in as well, because I hate having those files versioned.  Probably more of an issue for web developers